# Шифрование строки\двоичного файла по паролю

Tags: delphi, шифрование

Привет, друзья.
Требуется функция, в которой было бы реализовано **криптоустойчивое** обратимое шифрование текста или (ещё лучше!) двоичного файла по ключу (паролю в виде строки).

Который день пытаюсь найти в поисковиках что-нибудь стоящее, а натыкаюсь на ерунду. Изобретать велосипед лишний раз не горю желанием :(

Покажите, пожалуйста, пример или накидайте пару ссылок. Заранее спасибо!

С уважением :)

Comment: Начните с изучения существующих обратимых алгоритмов шифрования, выберите подходящий вам, а затем ищите реализацию конкретного алгоритма, если не хотите изобретать велосипед.

Comment: Так вы название какое-нибудь напишите, иначе полезность вашего совета стремится к нулю :(

Comment: На php примеров куча, а вот у delphi с этим проблемы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В гугле Вам нужна одна строчка - AES. Разберитесь с алгоритмическими основами и реализуйте его.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное. То, что доктор прописал :-)